# USB WiFi Adapter not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, adapter

I am a new Ubuntu user. I've heard it's very cool, so I just installed it.
My new Leoxsys mini USB adapter, which works fine in Windows XP, is not working in Ubuntu.
So, I need some help regarding that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to Leoxsys, your adapter is Linux supported.  What I've found out that they have a different way of supplying drivers.  On their support page for that adapter, they only list Later Windows Driver, when in fact that file includes Linux, Windows, and Mac OS drivers.  So here is where you can [download](http://www.leoxsys.com/download/LEO-NANO150N_All_DRIVER_22112012.zip) the driver.

Once the download is done, un-zip the file, and inside you will see three folders, just open the Linux folder, and you will see the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Get the linux drivers from [here](http://www.leoxsys.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=vmj_color_plus.tpl&category_id=10&product_id=39&vmcchk=1&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=22) and install it

If you have Leoxsys Nano Wifi Adapter,

Getting the linux drivers from the product website and all didnt work for me for this device.

To get it to work, just follow these steps (make sure you have an active internet connection):

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run these commands in sequence:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
```

then:

```
mkdir ~/RTL8188EU
```

then:

```
cd ~/RTL8188EU
```

then:

```
git clone git://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
```

then:

```
cd ~/RTL8188EU/rtl8188eu
```

then:

```
make
```

then:

```
sudo make install
```

then

```
sudo cp -v ~/RTL8188EU/rtl8188eu/rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

then:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

then:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

then:

```
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Wireless should spring to life.

source: http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=11261.0